# Automatically update data in a cell when a duplicate is entered from Microsoft forms

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automatic-update, microsoft-forms

I'm using Microsoft forms to create a user friendly data entry for assets that need to be constantly updated. The reason for using forms is I like that your able to use it on the phone as well and enable multiple people outside the organization to have access to it.

My vision is to create the Microsoft form with all the required data entry fields and once filled out the data is populated into excel as a work book. (I know this is how forms works but its more for a questionnaire / exam type application.) Once the data has been entered in and its automatically populated into my excel worksheet, if an updated data entry is made through forms by the user with the same asset tag number (which would be my unique ID) I would like my excel sheet to update that cell that has the unique ID previously entered with the new data instead of creating a duplicate or adding another data line.

I can see future problems as well if someone wanted to mess with the data and enter a bunch of data that was incorrect it would automatically change whatever data was previously entered with the new "wrong" data. Or if a user accidently filled in the "unique ID" incorrectly it would change data.

Would it be easier just to make everything in excel including the data entry form or is there another way to utilize/mimic the user friendly interface of Microsoft forms and the convenience of using it on a mobile device?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a sample file or table?

Comment: In general minimize use of text entry fields. Have drop downs, tie the form to the user (if they can only enter their own data). Possibly have a transaction table that has all entries, then a separate reporting table that only shows latest entries. Then you might be able to revert back to older entries. Good luck.

Comment: You may need to consider using Power Apps instead of Forms.